# Frameworks with Swift 2.3 are unable to run in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I am from `Objective-C` background but I am using some libraries which are written in `Swift` .As long as I use xcode 7.3 I am not facing any issues. But after upgrading to Xcode 8 I am prompted to convert to Swift 3.0. I chose later, but 
I get the following error:

> “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be
>   configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit >
>   Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or
>   use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly"

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue) link but no use.

I am getting some error as:

> 'inout' before a parameter name is not allowed, place it before the
>   parameter type instead' for ObjectMapper frame work.

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41072875/3548469

Answer (score 0):

For `ObjectMapper` framework with `swift3` compatibility update pod with `pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.0'`, Then clean & re-build, should resolve your problem for `swift3`. :)

Comment: But i am getting [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `ObjectMapper (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `ObjectMapper (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `ObjectMapper (= 1.3.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`  Specs satisfying the `ObjectMapper (~> 2.0), ObjectMapper (= 1.3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target. error while installing the pod

Comment: In that case you need to upgrade deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such a issue when converting code into Swift3. You must have to choose convert option firstly. It automatically converts the syntax into Swift3. After that uninstall pods(if any). Then install it again(to update versions). After that clean the code and re-buid.This will clearly convert entire code into swift3.

Comment: But my issue is "UberRides" is a sdk witch supports only swift 2.0. There is no latest update for that.

Comment: In that case need to talk with Uber support. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve legacy issue in Xcode 8.2.1 by the following steps :

Step 1: open your pod File and make sure you pod file look something like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your 
 project
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 target 'yourprojectName' do
 # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use 
 dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!

 # Pods for yourprojectName

  pod 'UberRides', :git => 'https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-
sdk.git', :branch => 'swift-3-dev'

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
 config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
end
end
end
end
```

Step2: run the pod install command

Step3: Clear you Derived data : Developer/Xcode/DerivedData you can easily get the path from Xcode->Preferences

Step4: Clean and build your project