# I compiling Swift 2.3 project and have this issue on Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, xcode8

I compiling Swift 2.3 project and have this issue on Xcode 8.1:

> “**Use Legacy Swift Language Version**” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

After conversion still have issue

Comment: What issues are you still facing.

Comment: Is it a warning or an error?

Comment: open and close xcode if you are sure you have done conversion

Comment: Edit > Convert > To Swift 2.3 and click next.. It just a warning

Comment: @Karthickhari - converting to lastet version 3 is recommended.

Comment: I am using numerous of frameworks and after convery I gate more then 300 issue

Comment: Set -->Go to BuildSetting And search - Use Legacy Swift Language Version -- No . Build and run.

Comment: @YogendraGirase Did you mean , not convert only change that flag ?

Comment: Ok...But last month i updated the xcode version and iam also using swift 2. and framework..I got an same issue...If i convert to Swift 3 it got more than 300 issue...ANd finally i convert to swift 2.3. clean and build...small issues were came.i clearde that..Now it's working fine.

Comment: @New16 This is issue about run Xcode 6-7 project on Xcode 8.1

Comment: @Karthickhari As most of them in Frameworks that is why thinking something is wrong

Comment: Ya..Iam also using pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '3.5.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'Operations'
pod 'SwiftyTimer'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
   pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging’
pod 'MARKRangeSlider'
pod 'Koloda'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Comment: Take one copy and tried to convert swift 2.3...Otherwise it will display "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue with some of my pods,
You can resolve issue by setting Use Legacy Swift Language Version to true in your project setting.

[image]

repeat this step for every pod which throws this error.