# Xcode 8.2 Use Legacy Swift issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try to run in xcode 8.2 with set "User Legacy Swift -> YES" in build setting, it give me errors for cocoapods only.

I receive the following error:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38466703/5433235 this should help you

Comment: have you set this flag for the `Pods` as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I compiling Swift 2.3 project and have this issue on Xcode 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054194/i-compiling-swift-2-3-project-and-have-this-issue-on-xcode-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Toggled the "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" from "No" to "Yes" and back to "No" for each(Build Settings). The project then built again.