# Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods, xcode8

I have a app with swift version 2.3.

When I try to run in xcode 8 with set "User Legacy Swift -> YES" in build setting, it give me errors for cocoapods only.

see below image:

[image]

**MY pod file:**

```
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 use_frameworks!

target 'xxx' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'
pod 'PKHUD', '~> 3.1'
pod 'SCLAlertView', '~> 0.5'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
pod 'ICSPullToRefresh', '~> 0.4'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 2.3'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 4.0'

end

target 'xxTests' do

end

target 'xxUITests' do

end


post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
    end
```

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@ziminalex/xcode-8-0-cocoapods-95d8e7a769a9#.io4x2qz6a

Comment: may be it is possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, I already did the same but still got error as shown in the image

Comment: Duplicate xocde-8.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue/40482708#40482708

Answer (score 2):

This basically means that the pods are built for different swift version than your current project.

In my case my app migrated to Swift 3 but my pods remained on Swift 2.3 because they haven't adapted to Swift 3 yet. You can do either of the two  things here:

1. Change your pods to Swift 3 (or whatever latest Swift version) by going to Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax.
2. Degrade your main project back to older version of Swift.

I hope this sheds some light on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing that worked for me...

Note that this error is currently in a pod, but could be anywhere in your project tree. I’m going to show you how to “allow” Swift 2.3 in this pod. Basically we need to enable “Legacy Swift Language”. Select your pod framework (by clicking on it in the error navigator) and under Build Settings find “Use Legacy Swift Language Version”

[image]

Set it to “Yes”. Than “Build & Run” again to test it.

Check out this post:
http://rebeloper.com/downgrade-swift-3-swift-2-3-xcode-8/