# Swift 3 conversion "has no member" error

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling, swift3

I am trying to convert my project to Swift 3, and have gotten most of the bugs handled but I am having issues calling my gesture recognizer. Here is my code:

```
func addGestureToView(toView: UIView) {
    let gesutereUp = Init(UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DemoViewController.swipeHandler(_:)))) {
      $0.direction = .Up
    }

    let gesutereDown = Init(UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DemoViewController.swipeHandler(_:)))) {
      $0.direction = .Down
    }
    toView.addGestureRecognizer(gesutereUp)
    toView.addGestureRecognizer(gesutereDown)
  }

  func swipeHandler(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: currentIndex, inSection: 0)
    guard let cell  = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? DemoCollectionViewCell else { return }
```

It gives me and error stating that both gestureUp and gestureDown has "no member 'swipeHandler'"

Also on the row "let indexPath..." I get an error saying "Argument labels '(forRow, in section:)' do not match any available overloads"

Can someone help out with the conversion fix for Swift 3? When I comment those lines out everything works so this is the last piece. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the underscore for label `sender` in the selector.

```
#selector(DemoViewController.swipeHandler(sender:))
```

About the index path, the new method in swift3 is:

```
NSIndexPath(row: currentIndex, section: 0)
```

Comment: That helped, but I still have the error on the indexPath row and a new one. The new error is the "use legacy swift language version is required". I have gone to the build settings and tried setting it there but none work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the edited answer, for the legacy support, see the related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue