# Alamofire doesn't work after update to Xcode8

Tags: xcode, swift2, alamofire, swift3, xcode8

[image]I'm using Alamofire in my project,after updating the xcode to latest version 8.0 I can't build my project.It shows lots of errors regarding alamofire:
My previous swift version was 2.2 and xcode version was 7.x
Alamofire will not be code signed because its settings don't specify a development team.
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Then I followed following links:
[Xcode 8 Beta 3 Use Legacy Swift issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue/38466703#38466703)

but it'll generate 193 issues.
What can I do about this?.

Comment: @pedrouan My xcode version is Version 8.0 (8A218a). I have already updated the pod file and there i updated the alamofire to 4.0 . But doesn't work.

Comment: That's OK. But you mentioned 'beta' in your question. `8A218a` is not Beta.

Answer (score 3):

I also facing this issues, when i update the Xcode to latest version. Alamofire gives lots of error in Xcode 8. You have to update your pods. If you are using the Alamofire through pods, then select your podfile and add this code.

/*

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

 platform :ios, '10.0'

 use_frameworks!

 target '<Your Target Name>' do

 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

 end
```

*/

And after that close your pod file. Open your terminal and update your pods using this command.

/*

```
pod update
```

*/

Now you can use the Alamofire without any errors. Hopefully it will helps you.

Thanks Mandeep Singh

Comment: Thanks. Did the same thing. Problem solved. Additionally I changed the Swift Legacy Version in build settings to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your cocoapods:

```
sudo gem update cocoapods --pre
```