# Cocoapods error with xcodeproj 1.3.1

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I updated to Xcode 8 and Mac OS Sierra, and along with it I updated Cocoapods and the pods I'm using.

I updated cocoapods with "sudo gem update cocoapods", and it did this (which was fine, and expected):

```
Updating installed gems
Updating cocoapods
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.0.1
Fetching: xcodeproj-1.3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.3.1
Fetching: cocoapods-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.0.1
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-1.0.1
```

But then after running "pod install", it gave me the error below.

Not sure what is going on...  Please help!

This has also resulted in Xcode giving me this error:

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

---

Here is the Cocoapods error:

#### Error

``` RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Consistency issue: no parent for object `Main Group`: ``
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:18:in `parent'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:118:in `source_tree_real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:100:in `real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:121:in `source_tree_real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:100:in `real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:121:in `source_tree_real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/helpers/groupable_helper.rb:100:in `real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/file_reference.rb:163:in `real_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in update_to_cocoapods_0_34'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:46:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:46:in `block in update_to_cocoapods_0_34'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:45:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:45:in `update_to_cocoapods_0_34'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:20:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:20:in `block in integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:19:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator/xcconfig_integrator.rb:19:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb:58:in `block in integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator/target_integrator.rb:57:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:129:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:129:in `integrate_user_targets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:63:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:610:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:607:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:117:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.0.rc.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' ```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution.  I used the Cocoapods App (https://cocoapods.org/app)

and

I added these lines to the end of my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

(with help from [Xcode 8 Beta 3 Use Legacy Swift issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue))