# "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" couldn't find in Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I installed Xcode 8.1 and started to run my project. But I got build error

> "Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly

Someone suggest to change "Use Legacy Swift Language Version” to true in build settings. But I couldn't find this key to set in Xcode.
Attached screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGQP5.png]

Comment: Select "All" from the selection bar. You have selected "Costomized", Expand "SWIFT_VERSION". What you found?

Comment: There is no change. please visit the link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGQP5.png]

Comment: I think you have selected two versions for debug and release!

Comment: Duplicate Xcode-8.1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue/40482708#40482708

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41072875/3548469