# Xcode 8.2 Use Legacy Swift issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an Objective-C project in Xcode 8.2.

I receive the following error:

> “Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Comment: do you have use Swift legacy language Version key in build settings?

Comment: Please refere this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue

Comment: Your question is *identical* to http://stackoverflow.com/q/38446097/1187415, only with "Xcode 8 Beta 3" replaced by "Xcode 8.2"

Answer (score 0):

Go to build settings then change swift version No instead of Yes.