# 'Swift Language Version' option is missing in Xcode 9.1 Build Setting

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode9.1

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520306/type-nsattributedstringkey-aka-nsstring-has-no-member-font) error. Tried to resolve it by the answer given in that. Using Xcode 9.1, There i am unable to see Swift Language Version option in build settings. I choosed All and Combined in that.

Here is the screenshot

[image] I don't know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have an Objective-C project rather than a Swift project. Objective-C projects do not have a Swift Language Version setting as a default.

You can add Swift Language Version as a User-Defined Setting, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240036/3220708).

Comment: Ok, I got it, Thank you @Craig Grummitt. I tried the solution given in the link you mentioned, but still i am having those errors.

Comment: Not a good answer. I'm running a Swift project and am getting this issue.