# AutoComplete Google Places in a Textfield in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps

I have a `UITextField` and a `UITableView` under the `UITextField`.

When user enter anyplace it show the relevant places to the data which user right should be shown in the table view. For this I have search a  lot to the third party lib's and follow step by step procedure of **google** but failed to get the results.

Now again I have tried the *Google Developers* procedure but not results so far, I have got API key in my `AppDelegate.m` file and done some coding in my view controller where I want to show.

I'm just messed up how to get my result, can anyone help me?

I'm getting this issue I don't know why because I have only used `Objective-c` code in my project from `Google Developers`.

the issue is this:

> "Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured
>   correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To
>   Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build
>   Settings editor to configure the build setting directly"

Comment: what is your pod file, Are all pod  lib used in your podFile is onjective C

Comment: i'm manually doing this instead of using pod, I have added three framework provided by google in my project and than generate a key for my project and than added the code given in google developers site. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: have u got my point? @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: yes but you using any swift frame work , what code you copy from google places , share any

Comment: GooglePlaces.framework
GoogleMapsBase.framework
GooglePlacePicker.framework (only if using the place picker)
GoogleMapsCore.framework (only if using the place picker)
GoogleMaps.framework (only if using the place picker)
Accelerate.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreTelephony.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework,libc++.tbd,libz.tbd,OpenGLES.framework,QuartzCore.framework,SystemConfiguration.framework,UIKit.framework

Comment: i have added these frameworks in my project. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: check this wrapper https://github.com/hkellaway/HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete

Comment: i have tried this before but not get any result. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: I'm trying this for the first time and really confused about the code can u guide me the whole procedure please? @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: i'm working on objective c language bro. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: this one https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView

Comment: i have just to add that folder from this link in my project? @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: Try adding your code & what you tried, and specifically the errors

Comment: can u come on the discussion i can explain all the stuff or any email id ? @CaplinYT

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the `Frameworks` you are using was Swift. So check each and every `Framework` you have dragged to your project.

If you are using `CoreData` you need to change `Code Generation` to `Objective-C` too if it was selected as `Swift`.

Find out more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446097/xcode-8-beta-3-use-legacy-swift-issue)

Comment: I have removed that error, now i'm facing an error that a header file is not found in the folders i added from google documents. @Himanth

Comment: you need to add framework search path for google documents

Comment: Where t get it , bro its first time so i'm confused to get that where to get that. @Himanth